# creating table in PHPmyadmin in local host shows error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

Am trying to create SQL table in PHP myadmin in local host when i run SQL code it shows error like

```
#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1' Ã  la ligne 25
```

and here is my full SQL code

```
CREATE TABLE `mobile` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`place` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`type` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile1` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile2` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile3` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`mobilebrand` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`mobilemodel` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`mobilecond` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`price` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`location` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`description` longtext NOT NULL,
`youare` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`name` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`email` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`phonenumber` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`datetime` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`view` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
`reply` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

when i run this in online PHP myadmin  in 000webhost.com it works there what about in offline in localhost i don't know whats wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

TYPE=MyISAM

with

ENGINE=MyISAM

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `mobile` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`place` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`type` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile1` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile2` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`ufile3` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`mobilebrand` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`mobilemodel` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`mobilecond` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`price` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`location` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`description` longtext NOT NULL,
`youare` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`name` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`email` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`phonenumber` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`datetime` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`view` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
`reply` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) Engine=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: am getting warning in other language how resolve it Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de

Comment: What version are you using on phpmyadmin?
Replace "Type" to "Engine" on last line

Comment: where do i find that

Comment: Code edited use above code..